# CMake file being added in linking step

Tags: cmake

I have a project with several sub directories I'm compiling with CMake. Sometimes, when I do `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && cmake --build .` I get `g++: error: mysub: linker input file not found`. For some reason, on the link step, there is a `mysub` added to the compilation command. It happens after the includes. Sometimes, cleaning the build directory and rerunning `cmake ..` will fix it, sometimes it won't.

The options I'm telling CMake to use are:

```
function(addcxxwarn opt)
    add_compile_options("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${opt}>")
endfunction()

addcxxwarn(${name} -Wall)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wextra)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wshadow)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wpointer-arith)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wcast-qual)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wswitch-default)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wcast-align)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wundef)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wwrite-strings)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wconversion)
addcxxwarn(${name} -Wunreachable-code)
addcxxwarn(${name} -pedantic)
addcxxwarn(${name} -funroll-loops)
addcxxwarn(${name} -fno-common)
addcxxwarn(${name} -fno-exceptions)
addcxxwarn(${name} -ffloat-store)
addcxxwarn(${name} -fstrict-aliasing)

link_libraries(gsl gslcblas)
if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    include_directories(/opt/local/include)
    link_directories(/opt/local/lib /opt/local/lib/libgcc)
    link_libraries(gfortran blitz)
elseif (UNIX)
    include_directories(/home/fitzpatrickr/include)
    link_directories(/home/fitzpatrickr/lib)
    link_libraries(gfortran.5)
endif()

add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-g;-Og;-Werror>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:Release>:-O3>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:-g;-O3>")
```

and

```
configure_file(macro_defs.h.in macro_defs.h @ONLY)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

I don't see anywhere else where things are added to link or include options.